# HCPL-3700 voltage detector opto influencing DUT due to low input impedance. Pump float and controller

Tags: opto-isolator, fluid-pump, voltage-detector

I am trying to monitor the state of a float in a septic tank using the HCPL-3700.  The float is connected to two screw terminals on the controller panel.  This float is normally-open with 120VAC across the terminals.  When the float rises to a sufficient height, it shorts and current flows through the float, triggering the relay for the pump motor.  This current through the float is not the full current for the 230VAC pump motor, which is supplied by a separate circuit.
[image: janky drawing]
Using the quite-helpful [application note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP2xQ.jpg) for the HCPL-3700, I created this circuit and connected it in parallel across the two terminals.  (My circuit is nearly identical to figure 10 on page 6.)  It works perfectly when bench-testing the presence of AC, but it fails when placed across the pump float terminals.  Apparently, the pump controller detects the 36k-ohm input resistance (2*18) as a short and immediately turns on the pump as soon as the HCPL-3700 is connected.

I tested a number of resistors to determine the threshold for the pump controller to detect a “float up” condition.  Turns out that anything less than ~300k-ohm is detected as short.  (The open float impedance is ~2M-ohm.)

Unfortunately, 300k-ohm is well beyond the limits shown in figure 7 on page 5 for a 120VAC circuit.  I’ve gone through every example in the application note and I can’t seem to figure out a clever way to use the HCPL-3700.  Ideas?

A little background:

Given this pump’s septic function, it cannot fail.  In truth, there are three floats on this tank, with some functional redundancy.  It’s a pretty common design.  I cannot risk a device being connected in series with the float, particularly a device I had a role in authoring.  I had hoped that the HCPL-3700 connected in parallel would not perturb the controller.  I was wrong.

The entire package is UL listed and I can't replace floats or other components.  The system has worked quite well for years, but I have no visibility of its failure until an alarm sounds.

Maybe there is an alternative opto with a bigger input impedance that would work.  I may be better served by using current transformers or a Schmitt trigger-based circuit.  Given the easy availability of the screw terminals on the controller, this seemed like a great use for the HCPL-3700.

Comment: The "application note" link is just giving me another copy of your schematic drawing.

Comment: so sorry.  <a href="http://www.slottechforum.com/slotinfo/Techstuff/CD2%20Diodes%20and%20Transistors/Opto%20and%20LED/Optoisolators/HCPL3700%20app%20note.pdf" title="appnote">application note. </a>

Comment: Given all the information and the constraints, I'd use another float, and monitor that. You would then have true independence and complete plausible deniability if anything went wrong, which seems to be your overriding concern.

Comment: I checked the other floats.  Identical.  The control board appears to use a much lower impedance value than I expected to trip the pump relay.  I guess that makes sense, but it was unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use HCPL3700. I think it was not really made to detect high voltages since it uses a lot of current, and hence power (~0.5W in your case, double for the 230V countries) - This means your resistors will get very hot!
I would recommend you to use a bidirectional high CTR optocoupler, that can work with 300kΩ. For example [LDA210](https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/LDA210.pdf/$file/LDA210.pdf)

I have tried it with 500k and it worked, but it is not recommended to go bellow 0.5 mA, so I would try with `120V/0.5mA = 240K Ohm` first

[EDIT]
I moved away from using HCPL long time ago and my new solution works very well for me. You can check the "sensing mains voltage" (top right) schematics from one my project in here: https://github.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll

Comment: Just ordered on Mouser.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @maxwellfaraday. For 230v AC I used 2 x 38k resistors and it worked, but they need to be 1 or 2w resistors, the resistors got hot